# Issues detecting CPU temperatures with Leap 15

Tags: opensuse, sensors

I have been using lm-sensors/sensors ever since to monitor CPU core temperatures on various versions of OpenSUSE up to 42.3.
But since the switch to Leap 15 (kernel 4.12) I ran into issues, particularly with Intel C602 chipsets on a Dell T5600 and another machine with an ASRock EP2C602 motherboard.
During boot time, I already get some messages like these:

```
coretemp coretemp.0: Adding Core 8 failed
...
coretemp coretemp.0: Adding Core 15 failed
```

Installing sensors and running sensors-detect, the process sometimes hangs in a non-reproducible way. If I get through sensors-detect, sensors still does not show CPU core temperatures, only the package temperature for one CPU and a lot of stuff that was never there before and obviously fails to read properly. Like 0rpm for some fans that are actually spinning and a lot of nonsensical voltage readings.
With older OpenSUSE versions this was never an issue. I got sensible values for DIMM and CPU core temperatures and that was basically it. On the same machines.

To make matters worse, trying to shut down the machine with sensors installed it waits for a lot of processes related to lm-sensors to be shut down first. This can take up to 10 minutes before the machine finally shuts down.

I have the latest bios versions available and the issues appear both with an upgrade and with a fresh install of Leap 15.

Any ideas what causes this and how I can get around it? I am pretty much done experimenting because even removing sensors sometimes causes the system to hang indefinitely.

Comment: Likely a kernel bug (another one, yeah). Wait for a kernel upgrade or file a bug, which no one will look at until they decide to EOL it. Then they will auto-close it.

Comment: I have got the same problem. Suse says they have fixed it, but only in obs.
https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1097021